# How does Craft CMS handle user's session with Redis

Tags: session, redis

Let's say I installed latest version of Craft CMS (4.2.5) with no plugins or modules or any file that could modify current user's session. Just plain Craft CMS.
When I went through records in Redis I could locate key with a value that matches `sessions` table for `token` field.

**Redis record**

[image: Redis record]

**PostgreSQL record**
[image]

If Craft CMS stores session information listed on the second picture like `id`, `userId`, `token` , etc. than what for we store the same token in Redis?

Honestly I thought Craft CMS will store all session related data in Redis only.

How does Craft CMS handles user's session with Redis? Why is relational database involved?

Answer (score 3):

<strike>I partially try to answer my question but It's still unclear to me why `session` table is used for storing user's session data too.</strike> For reference I use PostgreSQL database and "[fluent](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/config/#style-map-vs-fluent)" style declaration in my *general.php* file.

How session works depends on how you configure your session options in *config/general.php* file and certain directives in *php.ini* file.

Here's my testing configuration:

**config/general.php**

```
// The amount of time before a user will get logged out due to inactivity
// 180 seconds or 3 minutes
->userSessionDuration(180)

// The amount of time a user’s elevated session will last, 
// which is required for some sensitive actions. 
// 0 to disable elevated session.
->elevatedSessionDuration(0)
```

**php.ini**

```
; How long session cookie will be stored in browser. 0 until browser is restarted
session.cookie_lifetime = 0

; How long session data will be stored in Redis
session.gc_maxlifetime = 120
```

**How user's session is created**

1. When successfully logged in to the control panel.

   - A row with `id`, `userId`, `token`, `dateCreated`, `dateUpdated` and `uid` is created in `session` table in PostgreSQL database. These are required information for `users` table for example to look up a user and update `lastLoginDate` field which it's value would equal to `dateCreated` field from our `session` table
   - A key with value is created in Redis database which looks like the first picture in my question. If we would use *file* storage system for session instead of Redis than it's content is the same as the content saved in Redis database -> [see example](https://nystudio107.com/blog/the-case-of-the-missing-php-session#once-more-unto-the-breach-dear-friends)

Of course a cookie called whatever you set `phpSessionName` to is created in user's browser with encoded value which refers to I think `uid` field in `session` table. [This article](https://nystudio107.com/blog/the-case-of-the-missing-php-session) helped me before with some unclarities about session so I refer to it.

*Note:* when you set `->userSessionDuration(0)`, Redis session key record doesn't contain `expire` and `duration` keys which means session exists as long as you keep the control panel opened. There's more to it which I explain bellow.

**How user's session behaves when logged in**

`userSessionDuration` is the setting responsible for how long you stay logged in control panel. The `session.gc_maxlifetime` didn't play a big role in it unless it was set to less than 60 seconds. Apparently this is a time interval how often Craft CMS create `XHR` request in control panel. If `session.gc_maxlifetime = 10` than Redis session record would get removed and we got logged out after 10 seconds.

What I found out if user is logged in and not doing any requests:

- If `->userSessionDuration(0)` and `session.gc_maxlifetime = 120` than session record in Redis persists with `TTL` set to `120`. `TTL` resets back to `120` every 60 seconds because of a `XHR` request that Craft makes. Field `dateUpdated` in `session` table is also updated with a time of `XHR` request. So you stay logged in as long as you don't hit the button "Log out" or quit browser.
- If `->userSessionDuration(180)` and `session.gc_maxlifetime = 120` than session record in Redis persists for 180 seconds with `TTL` set to `120` if not prolonged by hitting "Keep me signed in" button in control panel. `TTL` resets back to `120` every 60 seconds because of a `XHR` request that Craft makes. Field `dateUpdated` in `session` table is also updated with a time of `XHR` request. So you stay logged in for 180 seconds.

So [Redis key `TTL`](https://redis.io/commands/ttl/) (time to live) and `dateUpdated` in `session` table is something like [`mtime`in PHP session file](https://www.poftut.com/what-is-mtime-in-linux-and-find-command/).

**How user's session is destroyed**

1. When you log out from the control panel. Both records from PostgreSQL and Redis are removed.
2. When `->userSessionDuration(180)` is reached. Both records from PostgreSQL and Redis are removed.
3. When `->userSessionDuration(0)`, `session.gc_maxlifetime = 120` and you quit browser. That is when `session.gc_maxlifetime = 120` kicks in because there are no requests incoming to update times in both records and Craft removes a session record from Redis database only. This is unexpected behavior. A record in `session` table stays even if `purgeStaleUserSessionDuration` time is reached. I still don't know why "garbage collection" didn't kicked in.

**Sum up**

Values you set to in `userSessionDuration` and `session.gc_maxlifetime` settings are important to keep user logged in according to your needs. `dataUpdated` in `session` table and Redis key `TTL` are also important aspects of session's lifetime which depends on `userSessionDuration`, `session.gc_maxlifetime` and activity in the control panel. A session records in `session` table are used for example for looking up a user in `users` table with aim to update for example `lastLoginDate`.